# SSIS package with flat file source causing overflow error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package that reads from a flat text file with the following format:

```
"Col1";"Col2";"Col3";"Col4";"Col5"
2012-06-18 00:00:00;0001;"99";"311";"0001"
2012-06-18 00:00:00;0002;"99";"311";"0002"
2012-06-18 00:00:00;0003;"99";"311";"0003"
2012-06-18 00:00:00;0004;"99";"311";"0004"
2012-06-18 00:00:00;0005;"99";"311";"0005"
2012-06-18 00:00:00;0006;"99";"311";"0006"
2012-06-18 00:00:00;0007;"99";"311";"0007"
2012-06-18 00:00:00;0008;"99";"311";"0008"
2012-06-18 00:00:00;0009;"99";"311";"0009"
2012-06-18 00:00:00;0010;"99";"311";"0010"
```

And inserts data into a database table with the same columns. In the database, Col2 is defined as DECIMAL(5,4). The package executes 9 rows and then raises an error. When I check data inserted in the database, the value at Col2 in the first 9 rows are 1.0000, 2.0000, 3.0000, ... until 9.0000. At the 10th line it tries to insert 10000 and causes an overflow error.

I don't know why the values are multiplied by a thousand, and I certainly don't want this behavior. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are the values in the database 1000, 2000, 3000, or are they 1.0000, 2.0000, 3.0000?

Comment: Sorry, they are 1.0000, 2.0000, 3.0000. I'm going to edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the SQL Documentation on `DECIMAL` datatype here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

The first of the Community Additions describes your scenario, since you're using a (5, 4) you can only have one digit to the left of the decimal.  You have a maximum precision of 5, and 4 of these are to the right of the decimal leaving only one spot to the right.  Thus causing your overflow

Comment: So, I could change the database column to DECIMAL(8,4) or something like that or change the input file to have values from 0.0001 to 9.9999, right? Can you think of any alternative solution?

Comment: You could change it to a string or int, i'm not sure why you're stuffing those values into a decimal in the first place